# Vue2 - What does a public/private method implementation look like in mixins?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, namespaces, mixins

I see that the following are documented, but **I have trouble visualizing how this can be implemented.**

```
// Even better!
var myGreatMixin = {
  // ...
  methods: {
    publicMethod() {
      // ...
      myPrivateFunction()
    }
  }
}

function myPrivateFunction() {
  // ...
}

export default myGreatMixin
```

*The issue I am having is that in a component that contains multiple mixins, how do we manage them, what is the best practice/conventions here?*

I understand how this would fix the issue I've mentioned.

```
var myGreatMixin = {
  // ...
  methods: {
    $_myGreatMixin_update: function () {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

However, as the question states, I am trying to understand how the **even better** approach can be implemented in a component.

**My wild idea, not sure if this would even work/make sense?**

```
// myMixin
const method1 = () => console.log('method1 firing')

export default {
  methods: {
    $_myMixin() {
      return {
        method1 
      }
    }
  }
}


// component
mixins: [myMixin],

data: () => ({
  myMixinMethods: {}
}),
created() {
  this.myMixinMethods = this.$_myMixin()
},
mounted() {
  this.myMixinMethods.method1()
}
```

It feels convoluted, so I went out searching for more answers and saw that there was an **even better** approach, perhaps with the pubic/private methods, but unfortunately, I don't quite understand how that is implemented, and if it would solve my namespace issue with multiple mixins in a vue component.

Comment: The question is opinion-based. " even better" - better for what? It works this way. "sure if this would even work/make sense" - IMO, no. Notice that the functions don't use `this` and cannot benefit from being a part of a mixin. Regarding name collisions, you generally describe the problem with mixin pattern in general.

Comment: Vue 3 does not recommend mixins anymore. I suggest that you use [composables function](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) instead

Comment: @EstusFlask I see what you are saying. Yeah so my question is more on how the "even better" approach can help eliminate the name collision issues. But as you said, it is indeed a flaw in mixin patterns. Would you say that the approach of naming methods like `$_myMixin_methodName` would be an appropriate workaround, or what is the convention here

Comment: @cantdocpp Unfortunately upgrading to Vue3 is not an option for this atm :/

Comment: It's acceptable but I didn't see much need for this. Since you supposedly have full control over your own mixins, usually there won't be much collisions. You can use composition api in Vue 2 and combine it with options in some way. And you don't need to use mixins at all for things that don't operate on current component `this` instance, this code can be extracted to regular JS modules. It's design issue, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 2, there is no built-in concept of "private" methods, but you can mimic this behavior by defining functions outside the component or mixin object, just like in the example you've provided. These functions will not be accessible from other components or mixins, effectively making them "private".

The "even better" approach you've mentioned involves defining a private function outside the mixin object. This function is only accessible within the same file/module and is not exposed when the mixin is imported into a component. Here's an example of how you might use this approach:

So, define mixin like this:

```
function privateMethod() {
  console.log('Private method firing');
}

export default {
  methods: {
    publicMethod() {
      console.log('Public method firing');
      privateMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

and on the component:

```
import myMixin from './myMixin';

export default {
  mixins: [myMixin],
  mounted() {
    this.publicMethod(); // This will call both the public and private methods
  }
}
```

So, you can some how mimic the behavior like that.

Comment: I see, but how would even better approach eliminate the issue of having multiple mixins in a component, and if the component gets big, how would one know where the function is coming from (from which mixin)?

Comment: Dude, mixins are removed from vue 2. instead there are composables which can be used on the way you want, and have great DX. I think with some trick they are usable in vue 2, but I recommand switching to version 3, if possible.

Comment: I know :/ unfortunately currently, upgrading is not an option. However, that is a great tip, I will look for work around for composables in vue2